# Asp.net Globalization gone crazy

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, global-asax

I've built a website that has 6 different language support. And whole language system gone crazy. It either opens with the requested language or half of requested and half of another one orrrr completely another one.

Here is a describe for how i built the system.

In global.asax i've done this;

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender,EventArgs e)

{
    //just to show my point
    if(RouteData.Values["language"] =! null){
    switch(RouteData.Values["language"].toString())
    {
       case "en-us":
             // at this point i'm changing the value of static enum that i've already defined in another class ,
          // just to reach it from other pages. You'll see what i mean in a second.
            Statics.Language = LanguageEnum.EN;
             break;
    }
    // Here is the culture changing codes. ConvertToCulture method is a custom method to get ISO code for language from LanguageEnum
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ConvertToCulture(Statics.Language));

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(ConvertToCulture(Statics.Language));
}
```

This is the global.asax file. And i have extension methods on every entity ( by the way , i'm using Entity Framework) to get the string for given language.

Of course you may wonder why i've wrote extensions methods on entities. In my database none of the strings are in the same table. I mean like this ;

for "Products" table i have [ ID(int),Name(int) ] columns.

for "LanguageStrings"  table i have [ ID(int) , EN(string) , FR(string)] columns.

And the "Name" column on the products is referenced to the ID column on the LanguageStrings table.

Here is an extension method sample  ;

```
            public static string GetName(this Product pr)
    {

            try
            {
                return pr.LanguageStrings.GetType().
                    GetProperty(Statics.Language.ToString()).
                    GetValue(pr.LanguageStrings, null).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "null";
            }


    }
```

In every page on my website , i'm reaching the names,descriptions,tech infos with these extensions. And also i have method to get strings from ".resx" files , which is :

```
     public static string ResGet(string key)
    {
        return Resources.Strings.ResourceManager.GetString(key);
    }
```

To the point ;

For example when default page requested , it sometimes comes all in english. Sometimes hall of the page is english , half of the page is french. Sometimes its all french.

Either whole page open with the language that requested , or half of requested and half of another one or completely another one. I mean its either 2 or 1 language appears...

It really is driving me crazy. And its happens randomly. I couldn't figured it out.

It'd really be great if you guys help me !

Answer (score 2):

Is Statics.Language a static property?  If so, you presumably have multiple requests modifying its value in a manner that is not thread-safe.  You may want to consider using a [`ThreadLocal<LanguageEnum>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) value instead if you feel that you need an additional store for this information beyond `Thread.CurrentUICulture`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. I've been able to figure it out (i guess) thanks to you...

Answer (score 0):

I've looked for the Thread-Safe operations (thanks to Nicole Calinoiu here). And i marked my Statics.Language property with [ThreadStatic] attribute as explained below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx

There was this note made me use the attribute to solve this ,

> "A static field marked with **ThreadStaticAttribute** is not shared between threads. Each executing thread has a separate instance of the field, and independently sets and gets values for that field. If the field is accessed on a different thread, it will contain a different value."

The system works fine for now ...